# Spring boot war deployment - Failed to start component error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application.
It's working fine locally on my localhost.

Now I want to deploy it to the hosting server.
Generated the war file using mvn clean package.

Uploaded the file to the hosting server and started tomcat.
Now I'm getting the following error.

Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/appfolder]

How to fix it?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myappname</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>           
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>           
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

error log

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5094)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 76 more

12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.020 GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1847)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)

12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.022 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [18,269] ms
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.023 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/manager]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.142 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/manager] has finished in [119] ms
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.142 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/ROOT]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.239 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [97] ms
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.240 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/host-manager]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.355 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [115] ms
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.418 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/docs]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.450 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/docs] has finished in [94] ms
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.450 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/examples]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.844 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/xar5ryilra4/appservers/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/webapps/examples] has finished in [394] ms
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.848 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-4453"]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.860 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-4451"]
12-Jan-2021 11:19:32.921 INFORMAÇÕES [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 19280 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a spring boot application run in external tomcat, you have to extend it to SpringBootServletInitializer. Modify your code as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Java3Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Java3Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

Also, below dependency should be present

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Those two configurations are already present.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml and any logs that you see on catalina.out

Comment: I added pom.xml and error log to the question

Comment: Issue seems to with hibernate. It has nothing to do with tomcat. From your pom.xml, you seems like using postgresql. Add this to your application.properties spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect or dialect according to you db version

Comment: I added that and now a new error came up: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution. So you are right. Seems it's related to a db issue. But the "Failed to start component error" error continues there. I checked with the hosting company if application.properties file is correctly configured (datasource, user...) and it is. So not sure where the problem is lying now.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it has nothing to do with your hosting company. Something is wrong with your configuration. spring is not able to communicate to your DB. Is teh DB port excluded from firewall (if not on same server)

Comment: solution to your problem definitely lies within your application.properties or DB server. Can you also try if you are able to connect to DB server from your local

Comment: Correct. It was indeed a problem on the application.properties. Stupid problem. Incorrect character in a huge strange mix of characters auto generated by the hosting company for the username. So that passed this error, db was accessed and tables created. Still can't access the app because now there's a different error. But that's another story. Thanks for your help!